# Diameter of certain graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I guess the following is true but i do not know how to prove it:

> Let $(G_i, i\in \mathbb{N}^+)$ be family of connected $d$-reuglar 
>   graph (same $d$  for all $i$), such that $v(G_i)\rightarrow \infty$ as
>   $i \rightarrow \infty$. Then diameter$(G_i)\rightarrow \infty$ as
>    $i\rightarrow \infty$.

I try the following (but it does not work):

Suppose the contrary, then diam$(G_i)$  is upperbound ( *i.e.* $\exists c \geq 2$, such that $\forall i\in \mathbb{N}^+$  diam$(G_i) \leq c$   ), that would be  contradiction to $v(G_i)\rightarrow \infty$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$

Any help will be useful!

Comment: Use the Moore bound for a fixed diameter to see that the number of vertices is bounded from above for regular graphs of fixed degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d>1$. It is pretty easy to show that the diameter $\Delta$ of any $d$-regular graph $G$ is at least $\log_{d+1}(|V(G)|)$.

Fix a vertex $v$, and look at the set $B_k(v)$ of vertices whose distance from $v$ is at most $k$. We show via induction that $|B_k(v)| \leq (d+1)^k$.

The base case is $k=0$. Indeed, $1=|B_0(v)|\leq 1$.

For the induction step, note that every vertex in $B_{k-1}(v)$ can have at most $d$ neighbors outside of $B_{k-1}(v)$, and therefore $|B_k(v)| \leq (d+1)|B_{k-1}(v)|$. By the induction hypothesis, this is at most $(d+1)^k$.

On the other hand, by the definition of the diameter $\Delta$ we have
$B_{\Delta}(v) = V(G)$, so $(d+1)^{\Delta} \geq |V(G)|$. By taking log we get $\Delta \geq \log_{d+1}(|V(G)|)$.

So the upshot of all this is that when $n$ goes to infinity, so does $\Delta$.